# Poisson Probability with rate $\lambda (t)=-(t-4)^2+16$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

> The rate at which customer arrive to the bookstore is $\lambda (t)=-(t-4)^2+16 $ where $t$
>   **measured in hours**. The customers can buy a book with probability $0.5$ and they can also buy a coffee with probability $0.5$ given they bought a book or $0.8$ given they bought no book. Find the probability of $k$ people buying coffee in a given day. A working day is 8 hours.

I am assuming that they buy a coffee with probability $0.5\times 0.5+0.5\times 0.8=0.25+0.4=0.65$ So on average every customer has a probability of $0.65$ to buy coffee.

What is the probability that exactly $k$ coffees are bought?

Is it the same as having $k/0.65$ customers walk in the shop?

$$P(N_8=k/0.65)=\frac{e^{-8\lambda(8)}8\lambda(8)^{(k/0.65)}}{(k/0.65)!}$$ and solve for $k$?. It seems very tedious.

> Notes: I calculated the total expected #of arrivals using $\int \lambda (t)=85\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: "Is it the same as having $k/0.65$ customers walk in the shop?" Hardly, since one does not usually cut customers into noninteger parts... Rather, consider that the flow of *customers who have a coffee* is Poisson with rate $p(\mathrm{buys\ coffee})\lambda(t)$ at time $t$ hence their total number is Poisson with parameter $\int_0^8p(\mathrm{buys\ coffee})\lambda(t)dt$, and you are done. Keyword: *thinning* of point processes.

Comment: I see, this would give me the expected number of people who buy coffee, but I need exactly $k$ of them in a given day. I am assuming I use the same formula, $P($k people buy coffee$)=\frac{e^{-8\lambda(8)}8\lambda(8)^{(k)}}{(k)!} $where $\lambda(8)=\int p($buys coffee$)\lambda (t) dt$ ? Sorry for bad notation

Comment: No, this does not only give the expectation, but the *full distribution* of the number of people who buy coffee. Let me suggest to read more carefully my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is **not** the same as the probability of having $k/0.65$ customers walk into the shop.  For example, taking $k = 5$, it is really unlikely that exactly $2/0.65 \approx 7.692$ customers will walk into the shop.  (Well, maybe less unlikely if the shop is located in King's Landing...)

What you have is a rate of customers walking in and buying coffee of 
$$
\lambda_c(t) = 0.65 \left(16-(t-4)^2 \right)= \frac{52}{5} - \frac{13(t-4)^2}{20}
$$

The number of coffee buyers is Poisson distributed with a mean of 
$$
\int_0^8 \frac{52}{5} - \frac{13(t-4)^2}{20} \, dt = \frac{832}{15}
$$

So 
$$P(k) = \frac{ \left(\frac{832}{15}\right)^k e^{-\frac{832}{15}} }{k!}
$$